# Show that the Lower triangular matrix is singular and find a basis for the nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
> \lambda_{11} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> \lambda_{21} & \lambda_{22} & 0 & 0\\
> \lambda_{31} & \lambda_{32} & \lambda_{33} & 0\\
> \lambda_{41} & \lambda_{42} & \lambda_{43} & \lambda_{44}\\
> \end{pmatrix}$$ 
>   Suppose that $\lambda_{11}\neq  0$, $\lambda_{33}\neq  0$, $\lambda_{44}\neq  0$, but $\lambda_{22} =  0$
>
> a.) Show that $L$ is singular
>
> b.) Determine a basis for the nullspace $\mathcal{N}(A)$

Attempted solution a.) It is easy to see that $\det(L) = 0$ since $\lambda_{22} = 0$ which proves that $L$ is singular.

I have no idea how we would determine a basis for the nullspace of $L$ although. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $\lambda_{22}=0$, then the first two rows are linearly dependent, but linearly independent of the third and fourth rows.

Comment: Could you provide more information on your hint or just expand upon it?

Comment: @Wolfy I think one way to look at it is, square matrix has unique solution only if it is invertible; having linear dependent columns means at least one of the columns can be represented by a linear combination of other columns, i.e. at least one of the column is redundant (at least one free variable exists). This fact shows the solution cannot be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your null space was $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\p\\q\end{bmatrix}$

Why do I have a 0 in the first entry? Multiply on the left by your matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\\lambda_{32}+p\lambda_{33}\\\lambda_{42}+p\lambda_{43}+q\lambda_{44}\end{bmatrix}$

And solve for p and q such that this equals 0.

$\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-\lambda_{32}/\lambda_{33}\\(\lambda_{43} \lambda_{32}/\lambda_{33}  -\lambda_{42})/\lambda_{44}\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I do not really understand your answer could you give me some insight?

Comment: To answer your first question the first entry is $0$ since when we row reduce the matrix $L$, $\lambda_{11}x_1 = 0$

Comment: So, you know why there is a 0 in the first place.  The vector can be of arbitrary length, so might as well but a 0 in the next place.  p and q create as generic a vector as I can make that might work.  Now solve for p and q.

Comment: What am I multiplying to solve for p and q? Is it $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: If you could just add some more detail on your answer I'll accept it and give you the credit

Comment: Seriously?  $p = -\lambda_{32}/\lambda_{33}, q = (\lambda_{43} \lambda_{32}/\lambda_{33}  -\lambda_{42})/\lambda_{44}$

Comment: Yes seriously It would really help me if its not too much of a hassle for you

Comment: I don't mean to be mean, but I have walked you right down to the finish line and you still don't see it.  Which says to me that you really don't have the basics together, and may need to step back and review from the beginning.

Comment: Your probably right will do

Comment: Sorry I got it now, just needed a fresh pot of coffee :)

Comment: Going back over this I just want to clarify why there is a $0$ in the null space you presented. Since we want to find some $x$ in which $Ax = 0$ for the null space then $0$ has to be in the first entry since $\lambda_{11}\neq 0$. Also,for the $1$ in the second entry, we could have made it to be any number right?